# python parser Access to resource was blocked

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup

When I try to parse HTML using python, the HTML says "access is denied".

```
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
mvideo_requests =requests.get('https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz-10/smartfony-205/f/category=iphone-914', headers = headers)
    
    
print(mvideo_requests.text)
```

Output:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Access Blocked</title>
</head>
<body>
    Access to resource was blocked.<br>
    Reason or support ID: ed2df5d3-5e17-4f3d-ae01-2f053d32a354.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works for me. Can't reproduce.

Comment: Might it be location based denial of access? Or to do with whether you are behind a proxy/etc....

Comment: @QHarr I will be able to go, well, honestly I do not know why it happened, well, definitely not because of the ip